# Codeigniter not loading model constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter

Update :

```
parent::__construct() or die("error1");
```

in the constructor of the person model produces "error1".

Where am I doing it wrong ?

I am beginning to learn CodeIgniter 2.2

I have a person_model.php file :

```
<?php 
class Person_model extends CI_Model{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();      
    $this->load->database();

}

public function get_person($name=''){

    if ($name==='') {
        $query = $this->db->get('Person');  
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('Person',array('name' => $name));
    retrun $query->row_array();

    }
}



?>
```

My controller has a function

```
public function view(){
    if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/view.php')) {
        show_404();
    }
    print_r("begin");
    $this->load->model('person_model') or die("Same problem");
    print_r("end");
    $data['title'] = ucfirst("view");
    $data['persons'] = $this->person_model->get_person();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

When I load it, I get 500 server error in console and the word *begin*

My CI logs show this :

```
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> CRSF cookie Set
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:33:57 --> Model Class Initialized
```

So, I tried to focus on this piece in my controller :

```
print_r("begin");
$this->load->model('person_model') or die("Same problem");
print_r("end");
```

I see only *begin* and neither *Same Problem* nor *end*.

Where am I going wrong ? Why does my model not load properly

*Update*
When I comment out the body of the function get_person, I get *Same error* displayed on browser

*Update 2*
I just checked my connection credentials in database.php file. It successfully connects to the database.

Comment: Forgot to mention : I'm using PHP7 and mysqli

Comment: try correcting spelling in the `Person_model.php` code `retrun` $query->row_array(); to `return` $query->row_array();

Comment: @SachinPATIL thanks for pointing it out. Now, I get beginSame problem on my browser while the logs give 
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:48:46 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:48:46 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 13-03-2017 12:48:46 --> Database Driver Class Initialized

Comment: Try ` $this->load->model('person_model') or die("Same problem");` in constructor

Comment: @Shyamali : did that....no change in the browser output or logs :(

Comment: Just thought if you are learning good to start with the newest version of CI3 v The latest is Version 3.1.3 https://www.codeigniter.com/

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thanks.....I agree.....however I need to be ready for working in an organization where they are still using the old version....thats why I too had to go for it

Comment: Is the name of the model file "Person_model" ?

Comment: No. If I do that then I get a proper error that the model can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->load->model('person_model')` to `$this->load->model('Person_model')`.
Make sure the database connections are correct.

Comment: tried that......same output : "beginSame problem". Is there a way to check db errors ? I have $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE; in my application/config/database.php file and $config['log_threshold'] = 4; in the cofig.php file.